# Unity & C# How to check image's height/witdth or name?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public class FadeIn : MonoBehaviour
{
     public Image m_targetImage;
     if(m_targetImage.height = 360)
         {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds( m_stayDuration );    
         }
```

So there's more code in this script but its not really relevant to my question. I'm using unity, and in there , I got this script attached to 2 images. I would like to find a way to differenciate between them, since they're both stored in `public Image m_targetImage`. I know their height/width. Is there any way to do something like  `if(m_targetImage.height = x) then` ? I seem to find no answer to this.

If needed, here is the whole code : [C# How to differenciate between Images in the same script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64829219/c-sharp-how-to-differenciate-between-images-in-the-same-script)

Comment: But, you DON'T have two images "stored in public Image m_tagetImage". That's a single image. What you DO have is two instances of the FadeIn class, with an image in each of those. I think you're best trying to tell us what you're actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly, you are wondering if there is a way to check the width or height of an Image, which there is:

```
if(m_targetImage.sprite.rect.height = x)
{
     //code
}
```

Comment: Actually yeah! Thank you so much! I've been trying to find this in hours.